# Fill alpha channel of png image with background-color

Tags: css, png, alpha

I'm using .png images with a alpha channel to change the image on hover. When
i hover the image the background color changes. So it looks like the images changes.
But now I have a problem. This works in every browser but not in firefox. In firefox somethimes a thin line appears next to the image. How can i make sure this doesn't happen.

This is wat happens in firefox:

[image]

And this is what is should look like.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it, is the wrong image the problem? also consider checking if the wrong image really has a 1px border not much visible in your photo editor. Could you also post code and/or a js fiddle to reproduce this problem?

Comment: The problem is that the thin line of the background color appears around the image. The image doesn't have a 1px border i checked in my photoshop. And the problem only appears in Firefox

Comment: code or it didn't happen.

Comment: It looks to me like this could be an issue with a border being shown or some padding with an orange background being slightly shown. You could try border: 0; or padding: 0; and see if that helps

Comment: Css:
.doors img {
 max-height: 350px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.doors img:hover {
 background-color: #f75414;
 
 cursor: pointer;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign 2 background to one element so you need to use 2 element like below:

```css
.object{
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.object:hover{
  background: #FEF;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
  <img src="https://wiki.videolan.org/skins/common/images/vlc_wiki.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You can assign a second background when the element is hovered over using a seudo selector, for example .object:hover {background: #fff;}